# SMTP authentication checkbox is not displayed in the e-mail extension plugin in Jenkins

Tags: email, jenkins, plugins, smtp, jenkins-email-ext

The e-mail extension plugin in Jenkins is not showing the SMTP authentication checkbox whereas it shows the credentials drop-down only. How can I set up the SMTP credentials? See the attached screenshot below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klgnz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phaB9.png)

Comment: Use the **+Add**  button to add your smtp credentials into the Jenkins credentials store, and then select them in the credentials dropdown.

Comment: @NoamHelmer  Thank you so much for answering my first ever question in the stackoverflow :) Can you also guide me what should be the option from "kind" dropdown for smtp authorization credentials. I have added the screenshot in the description

Comment: Sure, it should be **Username with password**